# Make imageview resize to fit its container

Tags: android, android-layout, resize, imageview, android-relativelayout

I use a relative layout to display a row in a listlayout. What I am showing is an imageview to the left and two textviews to the right. Both the textviews will only have a single line each.

I need to have the image such that it should be automatically resize so its height becomes equal to the height of the text combined. That way, the image height will fit the combined height of both text in all screens. Is this possible? layout is as below -

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/note_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/note_icon" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_img"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:includeFontPadding="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_img"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_below="@id/text1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />
```

As of now,note_img has a size of 96x96 and the image is shown in full size making the image area considerably large and the two text having huge gap between them.
Really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use fill_parent, it's depreceated. Untested, let me know if it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/note_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/note_icon" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:includeFontPadding="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @svenoaks, The resizing works fine, but now there is too much space on both sides of the image. Here's a pic -
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=2054c3c

Comment: the problem is android:layout_width="wrap_content" on the ImageView, adjust that with a hard coded dp, and you can get rid of the space. Trying to think of something better though.

Comment: Thanks, but that would again make it look different in different screens :(

Comment: I think this is a case where you no choice but to do it after the fact in Java, since there is no way of knowing what the width of the ImageView should be ahead of time. I have used http://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/scale-image-into-imageview-then-resize-imageview-to-match-the-image/ with success, although there is typo where he forgets to convert dp to px or something. You will also have to use ViewTreeObserver to wait until everything is laid out to get measurements on vertical LinearLayout. I would love to be proved wrong, but I don't think it's possible with pure XML correctly.

Comment: That was really useful link @svenoaks. Had osted to stackoverflow after an extensive google search :). I think I will resort to my earlier code and use different sized images for mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi.
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

After set the `Text` in `TextView` set the `TextView's height` to `ImageView` like

```
imageview.getLayoutParams().height = textViewheight;
```

Comment: Thanks @Homo Sapients, but I would like to do it in the layout xml itself. Also, there are two text elements. Hence need a non-computational method :) Thanks for helping anyway.